# Problem with adding js script to the django project

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a problem with include a js script file to Django projects. Script works with  tags in html file.

Here is my 1st try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css"  type="text/css" > -->
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

The 2nd try:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css"  type="text/css" > -->
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

The both tries do not work. Do you have any ideas.
Path to **js** file is `static/js/script.js`.

**settings.py**:

```
from pathlib import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
print("BASE_DIR", BASE_DIR)

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eeg_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eeg_app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from eeg_app.views import index
from django.conf import settings

**urlpatterns** = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index)
]
```

[image]

Css and image from static are included without issues. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Add your project `url.py` to question

Comment: Already added to project

Answer (score 1):

Serving static files during development:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thats still not work if I had to do something like that:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: @Oskar, Are static files loaded when you open localhost:8000/admin? Share a screenshot of your project directory.

Comment: Screnshot added

Comment: @Oskar, What you see if you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: @Oskar, And what happens if you try to access `http://localhost:8080/static/js/script.js`? See you `Page not found (404) 'js/script.js' could not be found`